# Scroll the content for each link from downward when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have fixed footer with some link. It could be seen here

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/mjKyc)

HTML:

```
 <li class="active"><a href="#">What is Facebook?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">How does it work?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Feedback</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>
```

There few links in footer, like `What is facebook?`. When user click on this link content of that page should appear from bottom of the page. Similar for each link.

How this thing is possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you please make this more understandable?

Comment: @kleinfreund: please see codepen, in footer I have few links. onclick of each link content for it should appear from bottom ..

Comment: Sorry but it is really hard to know what you need.

Comment: @HanletEscaño: I updated the description. did you get it now?

Comment: @kleinfreund: I updated the description. did you get it now?

Answer (score 1):

for the sake of simplicity load the content of the link and set `display:none`, when the user clicks on the link set `display:block`. like this

```
 <ul class="active"><a href="#">What is Facebook?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">How does it work?</a>
           <div id="aboutus_content" style="display:none"><?php include 'about-us.php' ?></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Feedback</a>
           <div id="contactus_content" style="display:none"><?php include 'contact-us.php' ?></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact us</a>
           <div id="contactus_content" style="display:none"><?php include 'contact-us.php' ?></div>
      </li> 
</ul>
```

this jquery function will work

```
$(function(){
    $(ul li).on(click,function(){
        if($(this).css("display")=="block")
                    ;//do nothing
         else
         {
               //find which li display is block (by its ID), set it to none and set current li display to block.
         }
    });
});
```